# How to change all products visibility according to their purchasability - Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, hook-woocommerce

I've been trying to find a code that can check all my woocommerce store's products' visibility. So if a product is purchasable, it should be 'visible'... And if a product is not purchasable, it should be 'hidden'.

this condition should be checked once per day, because the purchasability of the product changes automatically everyday.

I tried using:
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_visibility_options', 'hide_prods_if_not_purchasable' , 0 );

but I couldn't get the function right, I guess!!

I appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a way to kick this off daily, if you have a cron job that runs every day that will be fine.

Then you'll need to loop through each product, but this should work once you've got the products.

```php
foreach ( $products as $product ) {
    if ( $product->is_purchasable() ) {
        $product->set_catalog_visibility( 'visible' );
        $product->save();
        continue;
    }
    $product->set_catalog_visibility( 'hidden' );
    $product->save();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help “opr”, I really appreciate it.

I tried your code after adding an action, but it seems there is something wrong because I got an error!!

Can you please check it??
this is the code with add_action I used:

`
function hide_prods_if_not_purchasable($array)
{   
    /// Your Code Here 
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_visibility_options', 'hide_prods_if_not_purchasable' , 0 );
`

I’d also like to know how to set it as a cron job for this, please.

Comment: Ok.. I created a cron job using "wp control" plugin, and added your code there.. but nothing happened.. I guess it's not working.. any ideas????

Comment: That is not the right hook to use, that hook only affects the list of visibility options, for example the ones you can choose when editing a product. You will need to get a list of products (fetch them from the database using WP_Query) then loop over each product using the code above

Comment: I’m not using hooks now, as I’m using cron jobs alone.. It’s not working either!!
How can I fetch the products from DB using WP-Query?? Can you help me with the entire code please?

Comment: @cloud-wordpress see if this helps https://spineycactus.wordpress.com/2023/04/24/how-to-get-all-products-from-the-database-using-wp_query/